# Wordpress: where to register custom post types?

Tags: wordpress

The docs clearly mention [how to create a new post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) with `register_post_type` but fails to mention in which file the code should go.

Anyone know where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example at the bottom of the page, `register_post_type` is called from the `init` hook.